# Is it possible to access, with CSS or JavaScript, the pop-up that appears if an input doesn't match its pattern attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was playing with the pattern attribute and, of course, attempted to submit the `form` with a string that deliberately did not match the required pattern, given the HTML:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" pattern="[A-Z]{2,3}" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zbwJP/).

I attempted to submit with `1`, which of course resulted in error-handling by the browser (Chrome 21):

[image]

I tried to right-click the pop-up, and 'inspect element,' but so far as the Web-developer tools were concerned I seemed to be inspecting the `input` element (which makes sense, I suppose), rather than the pop-up dialogue. So, I was wondering: is it possible to access/interact with this dialogue via JavaScript (for responsive enhancements) or by CSS (for styling)?

The main goal would be to offer high-contrast alternatives for user-enhancements, or simply pop-ups consistent with a site's styling and colour-schemes.

Edited to link to MDN for compatibility information:

- [HTML 5 form attribute compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input#compat-desktop).

Comment: related: http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/Styling%20Form%20Controls#WebKitr82180orlater

Comment: @jbabey: wow; that seems to be an actual answer, then (in the case of Webkit, at least). There are days I suspect there's a giant mailing list I'm missing out on... =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to style the popup, but support is limited and only works in webkit based browsers. As for the other browsers, there may be similar psuedoselectors that you can use, but I was not able to find them.

It boils down to being able to find/know the DOM structure of those popups, and then adding CSS that will modify them. After all, they're just DOM elements.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/zbwJP/1/

[documentation](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/Styling%20Form%20Controls#WebKitr82180orlater)

Answer (score 2):

In the latest iterations of Chrome, support has been added for following pseudo selectors

```
::-webkit-validation-bubble{}
::-webkit-validation-bubble-top-outer-arrow{}
::-webkit-validation-bubble-top-inner-arrow{}
::-webkit-validation-bubble-message{}
```

Check [here](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/Styling%20Form%20Controls) for some info

Firefox has support for the element attribute x-moz-errormessage which enables you to change the text of the error message. Info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/element/input#section_5)

Could not find if Firefox has a way to style the error bubbles.

Answer (score 0):

The pop-up dialog differencitates from browser to browser.
There is no way to style these (for cross-broser).

A work-around would be to use JQuery's pop-up dialogs, which you could bind to that event.

More about this, you'll find here:

> http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: While I'm happy, as must be obvious from reading the question, to *use* JavaScript, I'd rather use the native browser-features than re-implement and/or work around them. Despite the incomplete browser compatibility/implementation.

Comment: Okay :) Well if possible, try to use the native browser-features in browsers where it works and if there are browsers which are left over, you could try to use a JQuery dialog instead - so you have a solution everywhere..